# MDX: Make Measure Value 0 based on flag

Tags: ssas, mdx

Would much appreciate any help on this.

I have a measure called "Sales" populated with values, however i am trying to turn the "Sales" value to 0, whenever the "Sales Flag" is set to 0.

Important Note: The Sales Flag is based on Date (lowest level of detail).

[image]

The difficulty that i am really experiencing and cant get a grip on, is how i am trying the display the MDX outcome.

As explained above, i would want to make the "Sales" value 0 whenever we have a 0 in the "Sales Flag" (which is based on the Date), but when I run the MDX Script I would wan't on the ROWS to NOT display the Date, but instead just the Week (higher Level to Date), as below shows:

[image]

I really have spent hours on this and can't seem to understand how we can create this needed custom Sales measure based on the Sales Flag on the date level, but having the MDX outcome display ROWS on Week level.

Laz

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the member in the MDX before the select. Something like that:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Fixed Sales] as IIF([Sales Flag].currentMember=1,[Sales], 0)

SELECT [Measures].[Fixed Sales] on 0, [Sales Flag] on 1 from [Cube]
```

I am writing the code without SSAS here so it might not be the 100% correct syntax but you can get the general idea ;)

You can add the iif in the SELECT part but I find creating member to be the cleaner solution.

```
SELECT IIF([Sales Flag].currentMember=1,[Sales], 0) on 0, [Sales Flag] on 1 from [Cube]
```

If you have a control over the cube in SSAS you can create a calculated member there and you can access it easier.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will be sure to look into your response and get back to you with an update :)

Comment: I don't have SSAS currently on this PC to test the query but you got the idea ;) If you often need that metric though I would move the logic to the CUBE and keep the mdx queries simple

Comment: Sorry, Veselin, but I don't think it will work because on Week level Sales Flag will be aggregated as a SUM and we'll never see 0 (or 1) unless all members (one member) have this flag as 0 (as 1).

Comment: If you do it in the cube then it will work. If you aggregate on a Week Level for the MDX and the calculated member is on the day (or even on the key of the dimension) then the value will be correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate on day level"? I see only SCOPE option here. Because if Sales Flag is not on the axis this part will not work: `[Sales Flag].currentMember`.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear if Veselin's answer works for you, but if not...

Several approaches are also possible.

1. Use `Measure expression` for Sales measure:

[image: Measure Expression]

2. Use `SCOPE` command for Day level (if it's Key level of Date dimension). If it's not a key level you have to aggregate on EVERY level (week, year etc) to emulate AggregateFunction of Sales measure but with updated behavior for one flag:

   SCOPE([Date].[Your Date Hierarchy].[Day].members,[Measures].[Sales]);
   THIS=IIF([Sales Flag].CurrentMember = 1,[Measures].[Sales],0);
   END SCOPE;
3. Update logic in `DSV` to multiply Sales column by SalesFlag. This is the easiest way from T-SQL perspective.